# How to get Google Cloudshell Curl request to work with https

Tags: curl, google-cloud-shell

I am using Google Cloudshell.  I am trying to follow their example at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-speech-intro/index.html#7, which says to use the command

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @request.json \
"https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=${API_KEY}"
```

but no output is created.  I modified the command slightly to

```
curl -v POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @request.json \ "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=${API_KEY}"
```

I did replace the placeholder text with my API key.  And now I can see the result:

- Protocol " https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
- Closing connection -1
  curl:

(1) Protocol " https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

So, I checked the version of curl being used and see that https should be working:

curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.52.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2r zlib/1.2.8 libidn2/0.16 libpsl/0.17.0 (+libidn2/0.16) libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.18.1 librtmp/2.3

Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp

Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL

My request.json file contents are:

```
{
  "config": {
      "encoding":"FLAC",
      "languageCode": "en-US"
  },
  "audio": {
      "uri":"gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac"
  }
}
```

I am trying to get a result along the lines of:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "transcript": "how old is the Brooklyn Bridge",
          "confidence": 0.98267895
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

}

Comment: remove the backslash from your (modified) command line!

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm late. You can try this:

```
curl -v POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @request.json "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=${API_KEY}"
```